# Pandas calculating percentages row based

Tags: pandas

I have my data frame looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd

ratings = {'rating': ['1','2','3','4', '5'],
        'F': [6,4,6,4,8],
        'M': [4,6,14,6,2]   
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(ratings, columns = ['rating', 'F','M'])

print (df)

   rating  F   M
        1  6   4
        2  4   6
        3  6  14
        4  4   6
        5  8   2
```

What I would like to do is get two new columns F_percentage and M_percentage. I wish they would contain the percentage share of each number in the F and M column from the whole calculated per row. Meaning:

```
 rating      F      M   F_percentage     M_percentage
      1      6      4        60%            40%
      2      4      6        40%            60%
      3      6      14       ........
      4      4      6        ........
      5      8      2        80%            20%
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of the total per row.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is important you can divide sum of columns to new DataFrame  by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)and add to original by `join`:

```
df1 = df[['F','M']]
df = df.join(df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0).add_suffix('_percentage').mul(100))
print (df)
  rating  F   M  F_percentage  M_percentage
0      1  6   4          60.0          40.0
1      2  4   6          40.0          60.0
2      3  6  14          30.0          70.0
3      4  4   6          40.0          60.0
4      5  8   2          80.0          20.0
```

If need strings with `%` convert values to strings, remove possible `.0` values and last add percentages:

```
df1 = df[['F','M']]
df = (df.join(df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
                         .add_suffix('_percentage').mul(100)
                         .astype(int)
                         .astype(str)
                         .replace('\.0','', regex=True)
                         .add('%')))
print (df)
  rating  F   M F_percentage M_percentage
0      1  6   4          60%          40%
1      2  4   6          40%          60%
2      3  6  14          30%          70%
3      4  4   6          40%          60%
4      5  8   2          80%          20%
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function that will do the trick and the apply that with the dataframe `apply` method

```
# female percentage
def f_percentage(row):
   tot = row['F'] + row['M']
   return str(int((row['F'] / tot) * 100))+'%'

df['F_percentage'] = df.apply(lambda row: f_percentage(row), axis=1)

# male percentage
def m_percentage(row):
    tot = row['F'] + row['M']
    return str(int((row['M'] / tot) * 100))+'%'

df['M_percentage'] = df.apply(lambda row: m_percentage(row), axis=1)
```

as pointed by other users, the `apply` method has performance issues. But if the dataframe is a small one, it is irrelevant. By the way it's important to keep in mind that, considering for example if the dataframe is going to increase in size in the near future

Comment: @jezrael if we are talking of really big dataframe, I think you're right. In the case of small df, that's irrelevant, and a mere style preference

Comment: Ya, agree, if small data or performance is not important then `apply` is OK

Comment: @jezrael anyway thanks for the clarification. I added that in my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution for you  -

```
import pandas as pd

percentage_F_list = []
percentage_M_list = []

ratings = {'rating': ['1','2','3','4', '5'],
        'F': [6,4,6,4,8],
        'M': [4,6,14,6,2]   
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(ratings, columns = ['rating', 'F','M'])

print (df)


for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    tot = df['F'][i] + df['M'][i]
    percentage_F_list.append((df['F'][i])/tot * 100)
    percentage_M_list.append((df['M'][i])/tot * 100)
    
df['F_percentage'] = percentage_F_list
df['M_percentage'] = percentage_M_list
```